# Documents as nodes and Security Mechanism

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm very new using either neo4jDatabase  or neo4jclient driver, I'm trying to create a proof-of-concept to understand if make sense to use this technology and I've the following doubts, (I tried to search over the web but no answers...).

1. I have some entities that have Documents associated with them, (PDFs, DOCx ...), is it possible to have a Node property pointing to those documents?  or Can documents be added as a Graph Node with a Lucene index so that a search could return document node and related relationships?
2. How does the Security works? is it possible to the users have access to the nodes taking in consideration their profile? Imagine that the nodes represent documents how can be implemented a security mechanism that the users only access their nodes (Documents)?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You can simply add a node property with a URI referencing the document of choice. That could be pointing to blob storage, local disk, wherever you store your documents. You *could* add binary objects in a node's property (by using a byte array) but I wouldn't advise doing that, since that just adds bulk to the database footprint. For reference, [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) are all the node property types supported.

Q2: Security is going to be on the database itself, not on nodes. Node-level (or document-level in your case) security would need to be implemented in your application. To keep data secure, you should consider hiding your Neo4j server (and related endpoint) behind a firewall and not expose it to the web. For example, in Windows Azure, you'd deploy it to a Virtual Machine without any Input Endpoints, and just connect via an internal connection. For all the details around neo4j security, take a look at [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/operations-security.html) page.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer... so looking your answers, if I understood well, I can have either the URI referencing the document or add the binary object in a node's property, but is is possible to use the fulltext search inside the documents?

Answer (score 0):

1) What David said.

2) For resource level security, you need to model this in to your graph. There's an example at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html